# mkdir with multiple variables

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm trying to set a mkdir with multiple variable in this location: `"photos/$username/$rand_dir_name/'file_goes_here'"`. Whenever I try to do this no folders are created, thus the image isn't displayed.

How can I change my code to create a folder with the user's `username` within the photos folder, and another folder within `username` folder with the value of the `$rand_dir_name`?

Here's what I have...

```
$username = $_SESSION['id'];

$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);

$location = "photos/$username/$rand_dir_name";

mkdir($location);
```

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir()` by default only creates a "terminal" directory, e.g.

```
mkdir('/foo/bar/baz');
```

would only work if `/foo` and `/foo/bar/` already exist.

Try the recursive option:

```
mkdir('/foo/bar/baz', 0777, TRUE);
                            ^^^^^---this
```

which tells mkdir to create any "middle" directories that don't already exist.